# How to change a value in an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, boolean

This function is for code to play a game of tic tac toe:

```
//--------------------FUNCTION--------------------

bool playCell(int player, int position, int gameBoard[]) {

    if (gameBoard[position] == 10 || gameBoard[position] == 11) {
        return false;   
    } else {
        return true;
        if (player == 0){
            gameBoard[position] = 10;
        } else {
            gameBoard[position] = 11;
        } // end if
    }
} // end function
```

playCell takes a player (0 for "O", 1 for "X"), a position (1 to 9), and the nine element gameBoard, and returns true if the move is legal (i.e. that spot is not yet taken), and false otherwise.  If the move is legal it changes the position to that players number (10 for "O", 11 for "X"). If the player or position input is invalid, it returns false.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the array to change its value to either a 10 or 11 depending on the player, and saving to the position they entered to play in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` keyword redirect the program flow back to the main program. So the code after return will not be executed. Change the position of `return`:

```
//--------------------FUNCTION--------------------

bool playCell(int player, int position, int gameBoard[]) 
{
    if (gameBoard[position] == 10 || gameBoard[position] == 11) 
    {
        return false;   
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (player == 0)
        {
            gameBoard[position] = 10;
        }
        else 
        {
            gameBoard[position] = 11;
        } // end if   
        return true;
    }
} // end function
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I know that that was a very simple problem, however that would have taken me forever to figure out.

Comment: When the array is output I need a X or an O to appear in the position the user entered. How would I write that.. I have a function that prints the table and need to write code so that if the user "X" chooses position 3 it will display
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  |  X |
+----+----+----+
| 4  | 5  | 6  |
+----+----+----+
| 7  | 8  | 9  |
+----+----+----+

Comment: You can do it in the main program. You have the player and position. So if the move is legal, change the value of `position` to `player`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a return statement prior to your array assignment here:

```
    return true; // HERE
    if (player == 0){
        gameBoard[position] = 10;
    } else {
        gameBoard[position] = 11;
    } // end if
```

this causes your code not to be executed. Remove this line from there and put in the correct place.